# Do I solve user's problem or answer the question?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer

Trying to help out, I sometimes find myself in a dilemma.

> Do I solve user's problem or answer the question?

I will give you an example: [JasperReports: Error creating table trying to use CrossTab without column group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344370/jasperreports-crosstab-without-column-group/)

NOTE: I have edited the question as this post went on; see my answer; the original question was only about CrossTab with the title: "JasperReports: CrossTab without column group".

For you that are not familiar to [JasperReports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports), the user is trying to use a function that is not the correct one based on desired output and his data source. (However, you could use the CrossTab, complicating the code and modifying the data source.)

The question states: "using the JasperReports CrossTab", I need to choose from these three actions.

1. Write a comment that the use of CrossTab is not correct, maybe suggest to close it.
2. Directly answer the question. Without column groups you can't do it; you need to setup your data source like an example of JRXML using CrossTab.
3. Answer the easiest way to achieve his expected result, ignoring that he states "using the JapserReports CrossTab".

**Action 1** is not very helpful to anyone, but maybe it's better to avoid confused questions.

**Action 2** is maybe the most useful for the community: if someone is searching the Internet, they'll find an answer on how to use CrossTab (even if, in this question, it was not necessary).

**Action 3** is the most helpful to the user since he wants a desired result (in this case I do not expect that the user will state that he can only use CrossTab for homework purposes).

Please advise on which action the community prefers.

Comment: lol - you will get moaned at, either way:)

Comment: I would suggest commenting to explore *why* they're trying to do it that way - do they just not know about the other options, or have they ruled them out for some reason?

Comment: For me it was very clear that he just wanted to achieve a result  and he just belived that he needed crosstab, so I felt that there was no need for clarification, hence he would have told no need for crosstab give the solution...

Comment: yeah I see your pain : _ )

Comment: Explain that it is an x/y problem and that y isn't the correct solution, then provide the correct solution. solving it incorrectly isn't very useful. You do risk being ridiculed by the op if they can't use whatever the "correct" solution is, and if that's an issue for you, i'd say just move on.

Comment: Also known as the ["shoe or glass bottle" question](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925).

Comment: I feel stupid for have to ask this, but what does "SO" mean in this context?

Comment: I feel even more stupied since with SO I intend the person asking the question, I have seen it in some comments.....and just went one accepting it not even knowing if this is correct way indicate the person asking the question, What is the correct way?, do you have an offical term?... (I edited the question for now)....

Comment: Ok perfekt thanks, I learn something new everyday @default locale i meant OP, question edit..

Comment: On Meta.SE: [Answering a question vs. solving a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17627) [When is it acceptable to answer a question that wasn't asked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143940) [If I solve someone's problem instead of answering their question should I post a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101714) [Answer what's asked or answer what's desired?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18552)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Whichever is most useful for future readers -  who might find the question in a search.**

It's important to keep sight of the fact that what Stack Overflow is trying to do is collate good answers to questions, and provide a source of reference.

Helping individual supplicants is actually more like a beneficial side effect of doing so - you need questions to give good answers in the first place.

So imagine in 6 months time - someone searches for the issue in the question, and finds this particular instance on Stack Overflow: What will be useful for *them*.

I would suggest there's no hard and fast answer, because it rather depends on how specific the asked question is. If they haven't given any additional constraints (such as - I can't use module X, it's not supported on platform Y) then take the general case - what would be the *right* way to tackle this problem?

If the answer is "don't do it like that" then that's an answer - albeit a poor one. If the answer is - "Don't do it like that, try this instead...." in which you lay out an alternative approach and rationale for why that'd be better... then this is the more useful long term answer to offer.

Some supplicants don't appreciate this - that's ok, they're not the only people in the equation.

Personally I will upvote answers that offer alternatives that:

- are at least related, given scope of question. (Same language, operating system, etc. - answering "just do it in `perl`" on a `java` question isn't useful, but doing so on e.g. a Unix shell question might be, given that `perl` is a very common install on Unix )
- Give a good reason why this alternative is an improvement. (I'm not fussy - there's some points that'll be a matter of opinion - some people really hate `perl` for some reason)
- illustrate the alternative, so that someone with no prior knowledge can at least make a start with trying it out.
- clarify when it might *not* be the appropriate choice (e.g. constraints that the supplicant may not have specified).

I will - if possible - try and finish of with "... but if you really want to do it with X, then then you need a Y".  But chances are someone else will make a post with that anyway.

Comment: "the fact that what Stack Overflow is trying to do is collate good answers to questions", this was exactly my main worry when posting my answer, (i'm not answering using crosstab...), but as this post moved on I realized the maybe the solution lies not in the answer but the editing of the question.... So instead of spending time on multiple answers why not edit the question?....

Comment: Cautiously - what you don't want to do is change what the supplicant asked. Especially not if there are people who answered that already. Asking a new - better - question might be worth doing though.

Answer (score 49):

If you can be bothered, do both 2 and 3. Make an example using crosstab for the user's desired output, and another with the easier method.

Comment: Sure about this, not only is at lot of work but maybe everyting is getting more confusing, Seeing  @jonrsharpe comment may the best would have been comment, then have the user to change the question and then answer...

Comment: @PetterFriberg Its how I would do it in this particular circumstance.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try do notify user if he can change the question.

Comment: This method can be very effective in cases where a simple glance at the code for the two approaches can tell the user why one is preferred to another and why the method they are intending to use is complex. I tend to face this scenario a lot where users ask for creating curves with CSS. I post a CSS version (not recommended) and then a SVG version (recommended) and the complexity of the CSS version hits the user.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Far too often, people assume that they're being helpful by answering a different question or making assumptions about the questioner's intentions. (Also, even if the questioner is able to be flexible in the solutions they accept, this may not be true of those who find the question on Google)

Comment: This is what I usually do. I often write it like "If you really have to use X, then you can do it like this.... But a better way may be to use Y, in this way...."

Comment: @user1354557 that does not happen "far too often". If a question is _"I have a shoe and a glass bottle, which shall I use to put this nail in the wall?"_, the answer is still _"Go buy a hammer"_. It is the only sensible approach, the industry standard, and so on. If you, as a question asker, have the audacity to ask the "shoe or bottle" question, then you better make very sure your question contains explicit language explaining what the constraints are and why a hammer is not an option - as to not waste everybody's time.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I will proceed (considering comments), when energy is not enough to provide 2 answers (2 answer is mostly a code challenge trying to use an incorrect method wrongly indicated by OP).

1. Use comments to narrow down the problem if necessary (in this case user wrongly presumed crosstab)
2. Post answer.
3. Wait for answer to be accepted
4. Edit on question to reflect problem and answer.

Hence, maybe the problem is not really my answer, but the question? If I edit the question, it will not be misleading for other users.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the best approach to take in theory. However, you will often get stuck on your first point.

Comment: Agree with @TravisJ and in addition to getting stuck what will also happen is that there will be atleast one other user who will give exactly what the OP asked for (I am not blaming the answerer but at times almost all of us fail to look beyond what is asked) and so OP in most cases will blindly accept it and stop discussing further.

Comment: @Harry so in this case someone else answer and user accept maybe it would be good to suggest an edit to the question?, hence skip 2,3 go to 4 ;)

Comment: @PetterFriberg: What I meant is somebody else could post an answer with the method not recommended (crosstab in this case), so suggesting an edit would invalidate their answer and should be avoided. What I'd do in such a scenario is just proceed to add a separate answer with the better method and very politely explain what's wrong with the other method (accepted answer).

Comment: It's entirely possible that future visitors to the site may also try to use the incorrect method.  They would probably be most appreciative of your expertise if you were to show why that is not the correct approach and provide a working alternative that helps them achieve their desired result.  In pretty much all of these cases the person asking the question will be interested in the functionality, rather than the implementation and knowing a better way of achieving that will be most important to them.

Comment: @Mike of SST, this was why I'm going towards editing the question, trying to answer future users that would like to use crosstab without column group...  No column group --> no crosstab, but to have sense there was a needed to edit the question!, and considering comments this seems not to be always a solution

Answer (score 1):

I don't really agree with, nor do I understand the "Do both" answer that currently sits at 45 upvotes. If a question has two possible answers that are vastly different, the question is generally too broad - or unclear.

If a question asks the classical [*"I need to drive a nail into the wall. Should I use a glass bottle or a shoe?"*](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925), then please for the love of your favorite deity don't post two answers.

Comment that they are most likely missing the most sensible approach for the problem at hand and that they need to go buy a hammer.

There are only two possibilities in such cases: they either don't know that they're doing it wrong, or they have extra constraints which they did not mention in their question.

If they admit to the first case, just answer with that: *"You're doing it wrong by using X for reason so and so, use Y like such: [code]"*.

If the asker is most definitely certain that their only choices are either a shoe or a glass bottle, while that is obviously uncommon or even unproductive, then they should acknowledge that in their question on beforehand, or ultimately when asked to do so in comments.

Answer (score -1):

What's your motivation in being on StackOverflow in the first place? Are you here because you want to help users, or because you want to play the SO game by earning lots of brownie points (also known as "reputation"), or do you have a mission to explain to the world the benefits of some under-valued technology?

Personally, if I see a question asking "how do I do this with Java and DOM", I'm quite happy to answer "it would be an awful lot easier to do it with XQuery" - provided I'm confident that the user would get real benefit from taking my advice, and regardless of the fact that they might not be able to take my advice because of constraints they haven't mentioned, or that they might be too stubborn to accept it.

Comment: The motivation is certainly to help users having fun doing it; but doing this I would like contribute to and respect the community (other users) since its several years that SO has been helpful to me. The brownie points are fun but you don't get much cash for them...., so I go for tags where I have fun..  by the way; I would prefeer jaxb...

Comment: Before somebody gets upset... I know jaxb is not a query language, the jaxb was  a joke, since Michael's mission was to explain to the world the benefits of XQuery.. cheers...