# Why did I get downvoted for helping the OP with their literal problem?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-answer

I hate that if the person asking the question wants to do something that is bad programming and you answer it telling them how to do that you get a lot of bad comments and negative rep.

Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730352/how-to-escape-special-charcer-using-json-encode-php/42735178#42735178), the OP wanted to extract a URL from JSON. I showed them how to do that and even though it was accepted I got -5 rep. I helped them do what he wanted to do. I think they should down vote the OP and not me because I just did what they wanted.  This goes for all questions, not just this one.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a personal help desk for beginners. Down-/up-votes are about quality of posts, and we want a high quality repository of questions and answers. Beginners questions don't fit these quality policies most of the time.

Comment: I hate to Godwin's law myself, but I'll take one for the team here. Are you familiar with the Nuremberg Trials, and how they ruled on Nazis whose defense was "I was just following orders"? Or, if we want to Categorical Imperative this notion: would you be cool answering a question that asked "how do I write a program that can gain entry into the nation'a missile defense systems and nuke Albuquerque?". How do you think people would vote on an absolutely, 100% correct and "helpful" answer to that question? How would you feel about throes votes? ..... How would you vote?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  Reasonably scoped beginner questions *are* in fact welcome here.  [Previous anecdotal discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=beginner+questions) would ***sharply*** contradict your assertion.

Comment: Closely related: [Do I solve the user's problem or answer the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308807)

Comment: @Makoto "Beginners questions don't fit these quality policies **most of the time**"

Comment: @Braiam:  I'm not even going to paint questions which don't fit quality policies with the same brush *at all*.  I've seen seasoned veterans of the industry ask questions which make them *look* like beginners.  The main thing here:  remove the presumed skill level and only look at the question quality.  That's really the only thing that matters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with XY problem that ends up with an accepted answer that is a bad practice?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288422/how-to-deal-with-xy-problem-that-ends-up-with-an-accepted-answer-that-is-a-bad-p)

Comment: @Makoto as said before: beginners are more likely to ask questions that don't fit these policies. Full stop.

Comment: Another reason why to avoid situations like this is that the OP didn't provide enough information in his question in order to adequately answer it.  The OP has followed up in the comments (a while after you asked this question) to say they aren't consuming the json in javascript, thus making the upvoted answer incorrect and your answer much more likely to be absolutely correct for this situation.  So basically you took a whipping here and on that question for answering correctly (assuming there isn't a better way for consuming json in java that obviates this issue). Oh, irony.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you know that there exist a class of solutions which aren't really solutions at all?  Sardonically they're referred to as "mathematician answers"; that is, answers which are syntactically correct yet do nothing to actually *address* the problem.

In this specific case, here's what you saw:

- The OP wanted to strip select characters from JSON which happened to be part of a URL
- You provided code to strip those characters out
- The OP thanked you and went about their way

Where the angst lies is with the community.  The community, knowing better, saw that your solution is not the most ideal for the problem space, and voted accordingly.  [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42737475/1079354) illustrates a more preferred approach to the problem.

The OP isn't *necessarily* at fault for asking a question like this, but you as an answerer certainly *are* for providing a poor solution.  Don't just think about the OP; you should provide a solution that is considered to be a reasonable approach to a problem.

Comment: But, I just did what he wanted to do. They showed how to do something that he didn't want to do.

Comment: @NoahCristino:  What the OP wanted to do wasn't what the OP *needed* to do.  I don't do PHP (wouldn't even to save my life tbh), but you see this in other tags.  Just because this is something the OP wants to do doesn't mean that it's going to be correct, or even tenable in the short term.