# Accepting an answer that solves my problem but doesn't answer my question

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I would really like to accept [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44023354/2814308), but as I explained in comments there, it solves my problem by telling me that I should do something different from what I was doing which led me to ask the question. In other words it solves the root problem I had but not the problem the question asks about.

Basically, I wanted to autoscale a chart's Y axis when the chart is scrolled, so I thought I needed to detect the horizontal visible area, so I asked how to detect the visible area and *I happened* to mention why (if I didn't, the question would have been as valid; it was like extra context I gave, actually unnecessary for the question).

User @teylyn wrote that if my final goal was to autoscale, I'd be better off using another approach, which happens not to require to detect the visible area at all. But my question was about detecting the visible area, and future users will find that question when they search about visibility detection.

What's appropriate here ? My doubt that accepting that answer might be incorrect is due to the above, but if I do that (not accept that answer) it would mean that the answer's author loses points due to having been too helpful, which doesn't exactly feel right.

In this specific case I also have the option of accepting another answer from the same user, which does directly address my original question, but it's not the one that solves my root problem; it's the one that solves the problem the question asks about. It would be a way to give the author the well deserved points but it totally feels like a hack.

[This meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308853/2814308) by @Sobrique seems to indicate that I should not accept that answer, and although I think that the term *supplicant* used there was uncalled for and that it doesn't fit my question, the rest does seem to fit my case.

But the help center [says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) *Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.* and I don't know if it refers to the root problem or to the derived problem that the question asks about.

Please advise.

Comment: Do whatever you want.  The accept mark is yours to use as you want.

Comment: @Servy I want to use it in the way it's intended for, and I know there is one. I'm just not sure what it is.

Comment: That *is* what it's intended for.

Comment: @Servy I hope I will get a bit more understandable advice, but thanks.

Comment: What don't you understand about the fact that you can do whichever you want?

Comment: @Servy Sorry, I have no time to loop.

Comment: Especially see the sentence that says: *The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.*

Comment: @Keiwan Thanks, I just read that and I was about to write that I'm going with that, although I think it's weird and the perplexities I explained in the question still stand, especially from the meta answer I linked.

Comment: @SantiBailors you can always edit the question so answer actually answers it. Be careful to not invalidate other answers when editing.

Comment: Personally, I'd choose the answer that is most appropriate to (best answers) the question *that is asked*, even though you have an XY problem (trying to solve X by asking about Y) and also have an answer that solves X.

As Servy has written; it's your choice. Do what you think is best.