# Is it wrong to make a more general answer when a previous answer had already answered the specific question?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72818313/13625293) which already has an accepted answer there. While it's true that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77903659/13625293) doesn't directly answer what's asked in the title, it's answering part of the title that could be the pattern of similar questions:

*"What is the icon for ___ in flutter?"*

Moreover, what prevented the asker from searching the icon in the Flutter webpage is because

> The webpage is really laggy, can't CTRL + F properly too.

I pointed out that we can search for icons in the [Material Symbols and Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons) page from Google Fonts (as the readers would find out that searching in this webpage is less laggy and has a better search system).

I also added that if the expected icon is not available in the Flutter icons collection, you may be able to find it in the [material_symbols_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/material_symbols_icons) package.

My answer then received 2 downvotes and 2 delete votes, plus a comment saying that it doesn't answer the question.

Is there anything wrong with this?

---

Please note that this is **not an LMGTFY answer**. The asker specifically mentioned about the *trouble searching for icons in the Flutter docs page* (as I quoted above), so I offered a solution to *use the search page from Google Fonts page* which has better searching experience. Since the Google Fonts page also includes icons that are natively not available in the Flutter icons list, as a responsibility I have to include the details to use the external package that has those icons.

Another important note: Whether the answer is addressing the question or not is **part of the discussion itself**. This meta question including its title was raised as it is, any subjectivity coming as a response to it may be discussed along, as it's what the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag is for.

---

The [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77903659/1) at the time this meta post was posted was:

> You can search for icons in the [Material Symbols and Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons) page from Google Fonts.
>
> If you find an icon that is available on that page but not available in the [Icons](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html) class, you can use the [material_symbols_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/material_symbols_icons) package and use the icon like this:
>
> ```dart
> Icon(Symbols.add_task)
> ```

---

### **Questions that are mistakenly thought as similar by the community:**

The discussion on [What should a minimal answer contain?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298804/13625293) addresses how a minimal answer should be made and what is the bare minimum to "clear the downvotable bar". The discussion **has not mentioned** about an answer that is meant to be a **more general answer** and whether a **deletion** for it is the right action.

The discussion on [Do I solve user's problem or answer the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308807/do-i-solve-users-problem-or-answer-the-question) addresses which one of the two approach of answering is more useful and preferred by the community, but **has not mentioned** yet whether a **more general answer** is worth a deletion or **should stay as a contribution** to the site.

Comment: The answer does sort of act as a 'Let me google that for you' type of answer, but it's more specific to the question asked and, in my opinion, is acceptable as an answer... pending the next issue: I wish it would have at minimum answered the question, by providing the values needed for the icons requested rather than providing the value for some *other* icon and thus requiring the user to look to another answer or follow the link to get the actual answer.

Comment: @KevinB Great feedback! The reason I put a link to a searching webpage (the Google Fonts page) is because the asker is having trouble searching in the Flutter docs (as I quoted in this post), so this alternative page should be the solution. I figured out this could be useful for future readers having the same issue, regardless of what icon they're trying to find.

Comment: In some tags people are very delete-happy. I don't understand why they're so eager to destroy other people's contributions. If it's wrong, downvote and move on.

Comment: @CrisLuengo This wasn't a case of a wrong answer. It was a case of an answer that didn't address the specific question that OP asked at all. Maybe that will help you understand.

Comment: @TylerH "not addressing the question" is still a subjective matter and should be part of the discussion. The argument that the answer partially answers the (original) question can still stand. Until then, I don't think it should be included in the title. The tag change should stand, though.

Comment: @TylerH If you think it doesn’t answer the question, it means you think the answer is wrong (“not helpful”) — downvote and move on.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan You _admit in your question here_ that the answer does not answer the question. How is it subjective? It's also _critical_ to the situation at hand; if it had answered the question, it never would have been deleted in the first place.

Comment: @TylerH "doesn't _directly_ answer" is different with "doesn't answer". The [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page mentioned _"What is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or at least a viable alternative. Your answer can say “don’t do that,” but it should also say “try this instead.”"_. "Don't do that" + "try this instead" is not _directly_ answering the question, but it's allowed. My suggestion for using the alternative page falls into this "try this instead" category.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan the question didn't ask how to find icons. It demonstrated a failure of the op to do so, as required "research" due to the current iteration of the ask wizard pointlessly requiring "research" even on questions that don't need it.

Comment: @KevinB As mentioned by Karl Knechtel, these kinds of "more general answer" do in fact answer the question. That's for the general case. But in this very case, it's even stronger with the research being included in the question body in which solving the failure itself will lead the asker [into the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Karls statements aren't gospel nor are they evidence that such answers are *always* allowed or useful.

Comment: As a baseline, all answers should *at minimum* answer the question, not point the user somewhere else where they can find the answer.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, but again, that's part of the discussion which more people seem to agree with. My emphasis on that _stronger_ position of this specific case may keep my argument valid even if Karl's statement about the general case does not stand. In this _discussion_ post we're combining evidence that come from different places of the site altogether to build the best conclusion. Until then, what agreed most by the people here is more likely to represent what the community is expecting from these kinds of cases.

Comment: At the end of the day all you're arguing for is the equivalent of "Here's how you google properly" being a valid answer because someone said they failed to find it on google. or "Here's how you ctrl+f on documentation" because they failed to find something in documentation. It's nonsensical. That's not to say all general answers shouldn't be allowed, but the one you're advocating for is absurd.

Comment: @KevinB That's a very rough comparison, and this is why it's important to understand the case itself. This "searching for icons in Flutter" case if very narrow, and giving the asker a way to search in the alternative webpage is in fact answering the question, in the way that the asker already knows what to search for (and even know the names of the icon), while the existing obstacle is just the search page. Hence giving the alternative search page is filling out this missing part, which answers the specific question, plus broadening the answer to also address any similar questions.

Comment: @KevinB I don't see a way to teach people "how to google properly" that would make any questions get its answer in a fixed, uniform number of steps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should a minimal answer contain?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298804/what-should-a-minimal-answer-contain)

Comment: @TylerH The first question addresses on how a minimal answer should be made to survive the "downvote bar", not mentioning about how it should be for not being a delete-worthy. The second one discussed the community-preferred way of answering from the two given approaches in the question. Both have not mentioned yet whether a more general answer is worth a deletion or should stay as a contribution to the site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general there is IMO nothing wrong with writing answers like this one.

> I pointed out that we can search for icons in the Material Symbols and Icons page from Google Fonts (as the readers would find out that searching in this webpage is less laggy and have better search system).

I'm not familiar with Flutter, and I'm not sure what programming language the OP is using it with (JavaScript?) or the extent to which that's relevant to solving the problem.

It seems like you are trying to explain that the webpage can be used to figure out names that can be used in Flutter - for example, if you see `Check` on the webpage, that tells you to use `Icons.check` to get the corresponding symbol in Flutter; and if that doesn't work, to try looking up that name in `Symbols` instead and use something like `Icon(Symbols.add_task)`.

I agree with you that explaining how to search for the icons and then use them is much more useful than simply giving results for two specific cases. The problem is that, as written, your answer doesn't really explain how to use the icons - only how to do a search. It isn't clear what to do after finding, say, an "Add Task" icon in the listing - how that corresponds to `add_task` in the code. One could possibly intuit that, but it's better to explain directly that a) the site lists the name that is needed in the code; b) mechanically how to create the necessary Flutter code from that name.

I also agree with Kevin B's assessment that the answer should include the originally-requested icons as concrete examples - *especially* since they *can* apparently be used "directly", when other icons might require additional work.

Here's how I would write the answer, based on my understanding of what you are claiming, and a bit of personal investigation of the page:

> Google Fonts maintains a [Material Symbols and Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons) page that lists icons that can be created in Flutter, which I more convenient and responsive than the official Flutter API listing. Clicking the button for an icon on this page will open an information panel that gives a symbolic name for the icon (and a Unicode code point - possibly in the private-use area - for the corresponding character).
>
> Some of these icons, such as the desired white-on-green checkmark and red X, are available directly in `Icons` with the corresponding name: thus, `Icons.check` and `Icons.close` respectively. Failing that, install the [`material_symbols_icons` package](https://pub.dev/packages/material_symbols_icons), look the name up in `Symbols`, and create an `Icon` from that result.
>
> For example, the "Add Task" icon:
>
> [image: "Add Task" icon consisting of an encircled check mark with a plus sign in the lower right]
>
> has the symbolic name `add_task`; it's not available in `Icons`, but can be created like `Icon(Symbols.add_task)`.

I've cast the last needed vote to undelete, and I hope you'll consider some of these changes (but feel free to write according to your own style).

Comment: After the edits I think your new version is even better than what I proposed. The screen captures from the UI also seem quite effective. Bravo!

Comment: "*In general there is IMO nothing wrong with writing answers like this one.*" This is incorrect--answers must _always_ attempt to address the question that is asked. Not doing so is 100% always wrong.

Comment: @TylerH My argument is that, in general, these kinds of "more general answer" *do in fact* answer the question. Certainly they may be *improved* by including a specific example matching the specific details of the question. But *often*, the "specific details of the question" are not really relevant and the *question* would be improved by not hyper-focusing. That sort of thing is at the root of people asking and defending clearly duplicate how-to questions that differ in some trivial detail of the input specification.

Comment: @TylerH _"answers must always attempt to address the question that is asked"_ If you mean the full question, then I'm interested in knowing the source for that ruling. Because the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page says that any answer that addresses part of the question is considered **helpful**.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan And any reader later looking for a solution to their similar problem is free to downvote an incomplete/partial and (*in their opinion*) **unhelpful** answer. I am inclined to agree with Tyler in that answers should strive to *completely* address the questions/issues/problems proposed by question authors.  After that you are free to point out and address the more general case if you feel it better helps future readers.

Comment: @DrewReese That shouldn't stop the answer from being contributed to the site. While downvoting is a valid action since it suggests personal opinions on the helpfulness of the answer, deleting the answer doesn't sound right. In the [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) help page, one of the reasons for deletion is when the answer is _"not even a partial answer to the actual question"_. Furthermore, in the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page when talking about partial answer it mentioned _"then you can contribute the results"_.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I didn't say you couldn't answer, but just point out that others may disagree with you on the quality of your contribution. A partial answer that answers the ***general question*** instead of the one asked by the author is eligible for deletion, no? Reframing and answering a *different* question doesn't make it a valid answer. If this is what you want to do then go create your own more generalized question and answer that. You can then go back to the other question and suggest that it is a duplicate of the more general case.

Comment: @DrewReese The part where _"others may disagree on the quality"_ is already addressed by Karl Knechtel in this answer, which is the absence of answering the specific question. This results in downvotes. The other matter is the close votes. There are no "reframing" and "different question" in this case, the "part of the question" being answered is the one I quoted in this meta post. The answer is a direct response to that part.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan If it's not already inherently obvious, the [tour] page addresses the concept, and the Help Center pages [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ("What is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that") and [Deleted Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) ("not even a partial answer to the actual question") address it more directly.

Comment: @TylerH The quoted sentence from the how to answer page continues with " – or at least a viable alternative". Furthermore, _"Any answer that fully addresses at least part of the question is helpful"_ as I've already mentioned, the alternative webpage link is addressing part of the question which is the issue with the webpage link OP included in the question.

Comment: @TylerH Continuing the quote, _"and can get the asker going in the right direction"_, surely the alternative webpage link can get the asker into the right direction, as it's explained in the question that the original webpage link is the _obstacle_ that is stopping the OP from getting into the right direction.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan Yes, "and". Not "or".

Comment: @TylerH Which part of the answer that makes you think it falls into "or", and not "and"?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan The part where it didn't answer the question OP asked, which is, for I think at least the third time, "what icons do other people use for the tick and cross mark in Flutter".

Comment: @TylerH That part comes from the question body, in which the quoted part included in this meta post also comes from the body. Both are _part of the question_, which makes answering any of them is a valid action and does not make the answer delete-worthy.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan someone stating "I googled something and didn't find it" wouldn't be a strong argument for showing someone how to google properly being the entirety of an answer, why is this case different?

Comment: @KevinB This case is different in the way it's very narrowed to the question itself, when the asker already know the steps to achieve what they wanted, with all the information they got (what to search for, the name of the icons). The remaining obstacle is from the search page itself, hence giving the alternative page is getting the asker to the right direction. I don't see a way to teach people "how to google properly" that leads any questions given on that scope to get their answer in a fixed and uniform number of steps.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan if the answer you produced included steps that solved the problem we wouldn't be having this discussion, it would have never been deleted.

Comment: @KevinB Having the steps included in the answer is an obvious improvement, yet it does not invalidate the acceptibility of the original answer. In the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page it says, _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better". The original answer was _brevity_, the improved answer is the _full explanation_.

Comment: *Brevity must at minimum answer the question.* not just explain why their research method was flawed.

Comment: @KevinB The answer does lead the asker to _get into the right direction_ with its _brevity_. This is all compliance with what mentioned in the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan it doesn't, tho, specifically in this case, since they don't even need a google font icon. They can use built-in icons directly.

Comment: @KevinB See how the answer is worded, "You can search for icons in the Material Symbols and Icons page from Google Fonts.". The readers clearly can understand from this statement that "icons" (refers to the icons being asked, which is Flutter icons) is searchable in the Google Fonts page. People coming for this question, including the asker, know what they're doing with Flutter, and understand that in the suggested Google Fonts icons page is what the Flutter framework has as its icons. Otherwise, the answer won't be relevant. This is also the point on how my answer is _answering the question_.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan the people reaching that question will be looking for one or both of two icons that they don't need to use that search for.

Comment: @KevinB Save your keystrokes, Dhafin has their mind made up, got someone in the community to agree with them (*I guess*), and isn't budging from their stance that their initial answer actually answered ***the*** question. I don't understand what point they are still trying to argue here. ‍♂️

Comment: @KevinB That doesn't make my answer not a valid contribution to the site. It still complies with what's mentioned in the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page, which doesn't make it a delete-worthy question. What agreed by the majority people here implies that the _deletion_ was a wrong action to take.

Comment: and i would still vote for deleting the original version of your answer. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I'm not sure why you think that's the wrong action to take on an answer that doesn't answer the question asked and instead is just a glorified "here's how you do research". It's just another iteration of [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Your original answer is apple on a sign with an arrow.

Comment: @KevinB Your reasoning to delete the answer is opposing what the [help to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page permits, which again is the part on _getting the asker into the right direction_. Furthermore, the "here's how you do research" impression is most likely came from having no grasp in the world of Flutter. While the reality the asker and future readers must be right about to use the icon, just missing the relation link between the name they know (in this case "tick" and "cross") to the actual icon names (which happen to be "check" and "close". This information ...

Comment: ... is explicit in the question, which is why giving the search page is obviously _getting them into the right direction_.

Answer (score -5):

You should only post an answer if your answer addresses the question that was asked. In this case, the asker wanted to know what others used for two specific shapes/icons in Flutter, and your answer did not attempt to provide a suggestion for either of them.

Thus, your answer was appropriately deleted, since at the time it did not answer the question (the content should have been a comment under the question, another answer, or perhaps an edit to an existing suggestion)

I'm happy to see your edits to the answer now include an attempt at answering the question posted by the OP, and have retracted my downvote. Please make sure your future answers always address the direct question that is asked! It's OK if other answers have been provided, but each answer must stand *on its own*, not just be *supplemental* to other answers.

Comment: If you understand the question well, the main problem OP did not find the icon is due to the not-so-good experience in searching for icons in the Flutter docs. Thus, giving a link to a page where you can search better is in fact answering the question partially. The [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) help page clearly mentioned this twice, _"Any answer that fully addresses at least part of the question is helpful and can get the asker going in the right direction"_ and _"So long as you fully answer at least a part of the original question, then you can contribute"_.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I do understand the question well. The question was "what do other developers use for these two specific icons in Flutter". Your answer did not address that request at all.  Your answer provided information that was a useful _addendum_, perhaps, but not enough to stand as its own answer. Thus, your answer was appropriately deleted.

Comment: My answer is a direct response to the **part of the question** that I quoted in the post. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144457/1423447) about partial answer that seems to be agreed upon. My answer has successfully addressed the issue with searching for icons in the Flutter docs. The rest, it's fine if the OP would response _"true, but I still need this and that"_ as pointed out in the second point of that meta post. The possible existence of this interaction doesn't make my answer should not stand.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan is *now*, clearly this answer is addressing the former version of the answer, that your question is literally asking about.

Comment: @KevinB Can you elaborate? The discussion have been all about the [version 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77903659/1) of my answer.

Comment: an answer on another meta from 2012 is hardly indicative of policy here.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for clarifying, I agree with that. However, the part where it says _"true, but I still need this and that"_ still stand with the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page, in the part where it says _"get the asker going in the right direction"_. "going in the right direction" indicates that the answer is not complete yet hence the need for the asker to response "still need this and that", and "the right direction" is what indicated by the asker by saying "true".

Comment: @DhafinRayhan What they tried is not what they asked. What they _asked_ is what _must be answered_ in any answer. As I and others have said here, there's no issue with providing _additional_ information to help OP even further along in their efforts. But additional information needs to be _additional_. You yourself acknowledged this explicitly in the question here and implicitly when you edited your answer to answer the question being asked, so I really don't understand why you're still trying to argue otherwise.

Comment: @TylerH The fact that the asker explicitly mentioned about the trouble only makes my answer in a stronger position. In fact, without that my "general answer" is still addressing the issue with getting the icon that OP wanted, and getting them to the right direction. My edit to the answer does not necessarily implies anything, the action was taken as the new edited answer is objectively explaining better. From the how to answer page: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_. The first one was brevity, the edited one has full explanations.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan the edited one has an answer to the actual question. I'm going to stop replying here since you already acknowledged explicitly and implicitly that you were wrong here, and I can't tell any purpose for the continued insistence otherwise.

Comment: @TylerH The edited one has an answer to the _full question_, while the original one has an answer to _part of the question_. Both which are valid according to the site guidance and do not fill the [requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) for delete-worthy answer. I'm not sure where you get the conclusion about who's wrong here, since I've dropped all the arguments to your accusations along the discussion.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan That's the nice thing about SO, everyone is free to form their own opinions about the usefulness of contributions of other members. Just be happy that the Meta-effect got your answer more visibility, and with enough prodding got you to at least answer the question posed by the OP. Congratulations, some people agreed with you, take your W and move on. Maybe your next answer will more completely address the specific concerns of the author. Cheers and best of luck to you.

Comment: @DrewReese Well said. The discussion in this meta post had already strengthened my insight about the reason an answer got downvoted, which primarily because people don't find the answer useful (had already known this, but getting the extensive explanations especially discussed on this very case, is nice). The next thing is whether the answer deserve a deletion, which seems still to be argued among the contributors of this meta post. Although the majority seems to agree with what Karl Knechtel said, there are still some nuances to this conclusion.